# Bootstrap table on mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

`.table-responsive` is supposed to make the table scrollable. However, for me, the table goes out of the container borders.

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/fbmor9e4/1/

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="manage-batteries-container" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="batteries-list">
        <table class="table table-responsive" style="margin-top:4em">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the css that is being applied I can see that both `overflow` properties are crossed out:

```
media="all"
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

I don't know why that was happening so I tried this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .table-responsive {
        border: none;
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

However I fixed nothing but the weird grey border that showed up. Now `overflow: scroll` appears crossed out:

```
media="all"
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
.table-responsive {
  border: none;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I don't find any css property that could be causing conflict. The only ones I defined for the table are these:

```
.table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td {
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
}

.table > thead > tr > th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}
```

How can I make the table fit in the container?

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/fbmor9e4/1/

Comment: Would be lovely if you could mock this up on JSFiddle or Bootply.

Comment: I edited my question including the jsfiddle, now you can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.table-responsive` goes on the `div` that wraps the table, not the table itself:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table>
  ....
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing -webkit-overflow-scrolling and see if that fixes it. The overflow scrolling messes with the normal overflow values.

Comment: How can I remove it? I tried setting it to `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: none;` but it doesn't work. However, the same thing happens with Firefox.

Comment: I was just suggesting completely deleting the -webkit-overflow-scrolling line, but check out Adam's answer below. It looks like the right solution.